# Delete Slide From Google API Using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-slides-api

I'm trying to delete a slide from a presentation I have on google drive. Currently authentication works and I am able to retrieve the presentation and get the slide id I want to delete from there. When I send the request to delete the slide it throws this error:

> Caught error badRequest: Invalid requests[0]: No request set.

Here is how I am formatting my request

```
requests = [{ 
            requests: { 
              delete_object: 
                { 
                  object_id: '<slide_id_goes_here>' 
                } 
              } 
           }]
```

Here is how I am sending the request to the API

```
service = authorize_service(Google::Apis::SlidesV1::SlidesService.new, scopes)
req = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::BatchUpdatePresentationRequest.new(requests: requests) 
service.batch_update_presentation(presentation_id, req, {})
```

What is causing this error? How should I be formatting this in ruby?

**Edit:**

To get the slide id that I want to delete I take this type of object

`Google::Apis::SlidesV1::Presentation`

and then call

`google_slides_api_presentation_object.slides.first.object_id`

Maybe this is part of my problem?

Comment: I'm sorry. My copy and paste was wrong. I modify the error. The request is not an array. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution for your situation, how about modifying from ``requests=[{requests:{delete_object:{object_id:'<slide_id_goes_here>'}}}]`` to ``requests={requests:{delete_object:{object_id:'<slide_id_goes_here>'}}}``? If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately that does not seem to resolve the issue as it continues to return the same error. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I could confirm it worked. Please try it in your environment. When you use this, please include ``Google::Apis::SlidesV1::AUTH_PRESENTATIONS`` in the scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
delete_object = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::DeleteObjectRequest.new()
delete_object.object_id_prop = "<slide_id_goes_here>"
request = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::Request.new(delete_object: delete_object)
requests = Array.new([request])
batch = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::BatchUpdatePresentationRequest.new(requests: [])
batch.update!(requests: requests)
res = service.batch_update_presentation(presentation_id, batch, {})
```

#### Reference:

- [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/storage_v1/service.rb)